# Why does the 2017 referendum have strong support outside of Turkey?

Tags: turkey, turkish-referendum-2017

In at least some overseas countries, if not overall, the "Yes" vote for the 2017 Turkish referendum was as strong as that within Turkey itself.

If they're living in countries with somewhat good, if not absolutely perfect, freedom of speech and the press, unlike what is happening [in Turkey itself](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/18139/270), why is this the case?

Comment: How is freedom of speech relevant here? Turkey's freedom of speech record is already abysmal, and I don't see how it wouldn't improve with a "no" vote (or how it'll worsen now).

Comment: @yannis within Turkey, the "no" camp wouldn't be able to express themselves freely, but outside of Turkey, they should be able to.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is a very complicated question. My naive take is that people in the Turkish diaspora that feel integrated into the countries they live in didn't vote at all, whereas those who feel alienated voted "yes" en masse.

Comment: @yannis - seems like a plausible theory, though I am aware of anecdotal examples contradicting this (surprisingly, I heard people be positive about Edrogan who had reasons to dislike the military over THEIR infringements on freedom and partly emigrated over that, prior to Edrogan taking power).

Comment: Keep in mind that the influence of Erdoğan reaches far outside of Turkey. https://www.thelocal.de/20170215/police-raid-homes-of-imams-suspected-of-spying-for-turkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One factor to be aware of is the strength of **the "yes" campaign abroad**. To quote [an article](https://theconversation.com/why-erdogan-is-chasing-turkeys-overseas-voters-so-hard-74469) from a month ago:

> Turkey’s president, Recep Tayyip Erdoğan is campaigning to greatly expand his presidential powers in an impending constitutional referendum. To win, he needs votes from the huge Turkish diaspora. His government is going after them with gusto – and in the course of just a few days, those efforts threw up a fully-fledged diplomatic fracas.

This "**diplomatic fracas**" may be another factor in itself. Both in the Netherlands (see the article quoted above) and [in Germany](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/05/erdogan-accuses-germany-of-nazi-practices-over-blocked-election-rallies), local officials intervened in campaign activities, citing security concerns. Decrying these measures as "Nazi practices", Erdoğan played this interference up in his favor.

Finally I would point out that the split in support for the referendum closely reflects the split in **support for Erdoğan himself**. He is a charismatic leader, and the people who voted yes were essentially voting their confidence in him.